# Calculating saved ebp, eip and current ebp

Tags: stack-trace

I'm a bit confused about the presence of a "current ebp" versus a "saved ebp."

When looking at a given stackframe with parameter x, is it not conceptually something like this:

```
0x8(%ebp) - parameter 1
0x4(%ebp) - eip here
%ebp - saved ebp
```

So you could get to the saved ebp by doing something like &parameter - 8?

What is the "current ebp (I guess the ebp of a certain stack frame)" if the saved one is in that position in the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

The current EBP value is the one currently in the actual EBP register. You can use that to access both the saved EBP on stack from the calling frame, the parameters, the locals (if any), and the return address (should you need to).

Comment: Thank you. Where is the saved EBP in reference to the current EBP? This should have really been my title question. Would it be right above the parameters?

Comment: The saved EBP value is at offset zero relative to the current EBP register value.

Comment: Sorry - new to this and just need clarification - but how would that be written out? saved_ebp = old_ebp?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Written out where? Like above, you mean? - that would be just (%ebp).

Comment: As part of a larger question, I have been asked to set the saved ebp to the current ebp. I found out that the saved ebp is relative to the parameter shown above, but don't know what the difference is between "current" and "saved." Are these 2 different values?

Comment: The 'saved' EBP value usually refers to the base page value (the address of the stack frame) of the calling scope, i.e. the value currently stored at offset zero in the current stack frame, as previously discussed.